# How to Ignore capital using lapply(str_subset)

Tags: regex, r, data.table, lapply, substr

I am trying to create a new column (D$NEW) in Data.table D which matches each row of D to a whole column (D2$COLUMN1) in Data.table D2 using str_subset. (My data structure is at the bottom)

```
D[,NEW:= lapply(D[,C1],function(x)str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), x)]
```

This works fine.
But I also want str_subset to ignore capital case. 
But when I use ignore.case(x)

```
D[,NEW:= lapply(D[,C1],function(x)str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), ignore.case(x))]
```

I get the following error

```
## PLEASE use (fixed|coll|regexp)(x, ignore_case=TRUE)
```

When I use ignore_case=TRUE

```
D[,F:= lapply(D[,V1],function(x) str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), x, ignore_case=TRUE))]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in str_subset(as.character(), x, ignore_case = TRUE) : unused argument (ignore_case = TRUE)
```

How can I manage to force to ignore cases while using this function..

Data:

```
D<-data.table(C1=c("a","b","c","d","e","A","B","C"), C2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))


D2<-data.table(COLUMN1=c("a"), COLUMN2=c("b"), COLUMN3=c(1:10))
```

Comment: Try `str_subset(as.character(DA$Participant.row), paste0("(?i)",x))`. The [`str_subset`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_subset) function does not seem to have any `ignore_case` argument.

Comment: @David Arenburg Do You mean, D[,NEW:= str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), C1)]?? Maybe I'm not using lapply correctly, but I need to match each row separately using each values

Comment: Never mind, for your desired output it seems like you need to loop over `C1`. I've misread your question I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error tells you that you cannot use an `ignore.case()` as a function. The second error is related to the fact that the [`str_subset` function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_subset) does not seem to have any `ignore_case` argument.

Use an inline case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`:

```
D[,NEW:= lapply(D[,C1],function(x)str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), paste0("(?i)",x)))]
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The ***inline case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`*** does the same that as `ignore.case` / `ignore_case` are doing. It makes matching case-insensitive. See [*more details on inline modifiers at regular-expressions.info*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). When placed at some place of the pattern, the part after it matches the string in a case-insensitive way. So, by placing it at the start of the pattern, you make the whole pattern case-insensitive.

Else, you may pass the `TRUE` to the `regex` function:

```
D[,NEW:= lapply(D[,C1],function(x)str_subset(as.character(D2$COLUMN1), regex(x, TRUE)))]
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `TRUE` is the value of the `ignore_case` argument (you may write it as  `regex(x, ignore_case=TRUE)`). See more details on the options you may use in the [*stri_opts_regex* section here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/stringi.pdf). For some reason, the `case_insensitive=TRUE` does not work. I got an error:

> *Error in `stri_opts_regex(case_insensitive = ignore_case, multiline = multiline,`  : 
>
>      formal argument `case_insensitive` matched by multiple actual arguments*

So, I had to replace it with `ignore_case`.

Result:

```
> D
    C1 C2          NEW
 1:  a  1 a,a,a,a,a,a,
 2:  b  2             
 3:  c  3             
 4:  d  4             
 5:  e  5             
 6:  A  6 a,a,a,a,a,a,
 7:  B  7             
 8:  C  8             
 9:  a  9 a,a,a,a,a,a,
10:  b 10
```

Comment: *inline case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`* - same as `ignore.case` / `ignore_case` is doing. Makes matching case-insensitive. See [more details on *inline modifiers* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). When placed at some place of the pattern, the part after it matches the string in a case-insensitive way. So, by placing it at the start of the pattern, you make the whole pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: `regex(x, ignore_case=TRUE)`, good, I will add the explanations to the answer.